# awk split integer into several parts

Tags: awk, split, integer

I have this integer `20120305193821` and I would like to split it into several parts `2012-03-05-19:38:21` for further usage in awk. Can anybody help?

Comment: What have you tried so far? We expect you to have at least attempted this yourself, instead of just doing a "gimme the codez".

Comment: Thought of splitting it with sprintf() or printf() but have no idea to seperate the integer into smaller parts. split() can't be used either since there is no FS I can split the integer on. Could try it with two arrays one for splitting on the index() sp=4,2,2,2,2,2 and the other one on the printout as a function. Have no short solution, this is the reason why i asked this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using gawk, you can use FIELDWIDTHS:

```
echo 20120305193821 | gawk '{printf "%s-%s-%s-%s:%s:%s\n",
      $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6}' FIELDWIDTHS="4 2 2 2 2 2"
```

Comment: FIELDWIDTHS is something new to me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Why not use substrings? It is just boring to write, but as you hint you have the indices?

```
echo "20120305193821" | awk '{printf "%s-%s-%s-%s:%s:%s\n",substr($1,1,4),substr($1,5,2),substr($1,7,2),substr($1,9,2),substr($1,11,2),substr($1,13,2)}'
```

output:

2012-03-05-19:38:21

Answer (score 2):

I know you didn't tag pretty `sed` so just posting here for reference -

```
$ echo 20120305193821 | sed 's/\(....\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)/\1-\2-\3-\4:\5:\6/'
2012-03-05-19:38:21
```